# How to combine javascript objects and then convert into JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have two javascript objects.Find below the two objects:

```
var tableRespondent = [{Id: 1, name: "abc", mail: "abc@gmail.com"}];
var tableQuestionnaire = [{Id: 1, externalId: "Q1", text: "Food Questionnaire"}, {Id: 2, externalId: "Q2", text: "Pet Questionnaire"}];
```

Now I need to combine them in below format:

```
var output = {Respondent: [{Id: 1, name: "abc", mail: "abc@gmail.com"}], Questionnaire: [{Id: 1, externalId: "Q1", text: "Food Questionnaire"},{Id: 2, externalId: "Q2", text: "Pet Questionnaire"}] };
```

And then I need to convert it into JSON as follows:

```
var outputJson = var output = {"Respondent": [{"Id": 1, "name": "abc", "mail": "abc@gmail.com"}], Questionnaire: [{"Id": 1, "externalId": "Q1", "text": "Food Questionnaire"}, {"Id": 2, "externalId": "Q2", "text": "Pet Questionnaire"}] };
```

How should this be achieved? I am fairly new to javascript.

Comment: By what logic do you want to ignore the first questionnaire? NB: JSON is a text format.

Comment: Something like: JSON.stringify({Respondent: tableRespondent, Questionnaire: tableQuestionnaire}); If you really want to exclude the first questionnaire then you need more logic for that.

Comment: try to read docs

Comment: `How should this be achieved?` by writing code `I am fairly new to javascript` if you weren't you'd have written the code, and not asked for the code to be written for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will help you

```js
var output = {};
var tableRespondent = [{Id: 1, name: "abc", mail: "abc@gmail.com"}];
var tableQuestionnaire = [{Id: 1, externalId: "Q1", text: "Food Questionnaire"}, {Id: 2, externalId: "Q2", text: "Pet Questionnaire"}];

output['tableRespondent'] = tableRespondent;
output['tableQuestionnaire'] = tableQuestionnaire;

output = JSON.stringify(output);

console.log(output);

//Json string
console.log(typeof output);
```